# Can you make a Spell Glyph of a spell that has the potential to target more than one creature?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting

The Spell Glyph section of [Glyph of Warding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/glyph-of-warding) states:

> The spell must target a single creature or an area.

Some spells have the potential to affect "up to X" creatures. The Slow spell, for example, states:

> You alter time around up to six creatures of your choice in a 40-foot cube within range. Each target must succeed on a Wisdom saving throw or be affected by this spell for the duration.

Can you make a Spell Glyph of Slow (or any other "up to X targets" spell), if the intent is to only target the creature who triggers the glyph?

Comment: Then there's Chain Lightning, which is worded so that it always has one "target" (the glyph version would need to target a creature, not an object), but can still directly affect other creatures (or objects).

Answer (score 16):

## Yes. You can make a glyph of *slow* that targets the single creature that triggers the glyph.

When used in a spell glyph, the spell must target only a single creature even if it has the potential to do more.  Using *slow* and specify a single target allows it to fit within the confines of the spell glyph.

### Target description language of spells usually allows for selecting one target

Some other examples of spells that permit for many targets, but also allow just one are:

- [*beacon of hope*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/beacon-of-hope) "Choose any number of creatures within range"
- [*bane*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/bane) "Up to three creatures of your choice that you can see within range "

Comment: It might be worth pointing out how this is different from the Twinned Spell metamagic restriction, which specifies that the spell must be incapable of targeting more than 1 creature; Spell Glyph only specifies that it has to target only one creature. It's the difference between "impossible to target another" (capability) and "does not target another" (outcome).