# Can Dream reach a target sleeping in Leomund's Tiny Hut?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting

Leomund's Tiny Hut spell states

> Spells and other magical effects can’t extend through the dome or be cast through it.

Dream states

> Choose a creature known to you as the target of this spell. The target must be on the same plane of existence as you.

**Can Dream reach a target sleeping in Leomund's Tiny Hut?**

The points giving me doubt are:

- "Extend through the dome" seems to exclude the floor/ground.
- Does "Target must be on the same plane of existence" override any protection offered by the dome, or is it just a requirement of Dream, and doesn't override any other existing limitations?

Comment: Perhaps related: "[Does the Scrying spell require you to have a clear path to the target in order to work?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/154565)"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Yes

It is primarily a matter of "Specific over General". The General rule is this (emphasis mine):

> A **typical** spell requires you to pick one or more targets to be affected by the spell's magic. [...] To target something, you must have a clear path to it, so it can't be behind total cover.

The Range of a spell is strongly linked to what you can target. It's primary function is to restrict what you can target:

> The target of a spell must be within the spell's range.

Now the Specific part: *Dream* has a Range of "Special", strongly suggesting that the *typical* (see emphasis above) rules for targeting do not apply. It also says:

> Choose a creature known to you as the target of this spell. The target must be on the same plane of existence as you.

It is more than reasonable to assume that the majority of creatures on the same plane of existance as you do not have a clear path to them. Yet they are still valid targets. Spells do what they say they do, and this one allows you to pick as target a creature that you know on the same plane of existence as you. This is a Specific rule, which usually trumps the General rule.

Therefore, not being restricted by LOS rules, *Dream* is not affected by the rules of *Tiny Hut* that say:

> Spells [...] can’t [...] be cast through [the dome].

No part of *Dream* is an effect that would have to travel in some sort of line through any part of the dome. Instead, the effect simply "materializes" in the target's dreams. Note: effects such as "blocking any spells cast into or out of the area" are present in other spells (*Forcecage*), but that is not what *Tiny Hut* says.

Bottom line: Yes, *Dream* can reach a target sleeping in Leomund's Tiny Hut.

---

### FAQ

**But Message explicitly says "You can cast this spell through solid objects."** Message has a Range of 120 ft and starts with "You point your finger toward a creature within range." Neither *Dream*, nor *Scrying*, nor *Sending* do either of those.

*(I'll add more as they come in)*

Answer (score -5):

### *[Dream](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dream)* has bigger problems than just *[Tiny Hut](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/tiny-hut)*

All spells require [A Clear Path to the Target](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#CastingaSpell)

> To target something, you must have a clear path to it, so it can't be behind total cover.

So, while the range is theoretically unlimited, it has a very hard practical limitation that there must be an unobstructed straight line between the caster (not the sender who might not be the caster) and the target. So, if they sleep in a bedroom, or a tent, or a *Tiny Hut*, or behind a hill, or over the horizon, they are ineligible targets.

Now, you can mount an argument that that isn’t the intent of the spell and that limitation is a serious, possibly fatal, nerf to a 5th level spell. That’s an argument I’m sympathetic to but it isn’t one supported by RAW.

The designers could have solved the problem by making the target the sender, rather than the recipient, of the *Dream* but the text is crystal clear that the *Dream* recipient is the target. The could have also explicitly overridden the clear path requirement but they didn’t.

As such, the *Tiny Hut* in combination with the ground it rests on will stop *Dream*.

However, if you DM rules that *Dream* doesn’t require a clear path then, while the *Tiny Hut* blocks it, the ground doesn’t.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110228/discussion-on-answer-by-dale-m-can-dream-reach-a-target-sleeping-in-leomunds-ti).