# How does spare the dying ranged ability work exactly?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cleric

What’s the conditions that need to be met so that spare the dying can work as a ranged spell.

Basically what I’m asking is, do you need to see the target?

The spell doesn’t account for that and the grave clerics ability doesn’t specify. Can I use spare the dying on a party member that’s around a corner out of sight but still within 30 feet?

Comment: How are you able to cast it as a ranged spell? It's range is "touch".

Comment: For Grave Clerics in 5e its range is 30 feet, which I assume is the specific case OP is asking about

Comment: I'll tag this with dnd-5e, as that game has a Spare the Dying spell and I am not aware of others who do (and most of the questions from new contributors who do not yet know they should always tag with game-edition are from 5e). Let us know if that is wrong.

Answer (score 19):

### You need a clear path to the target

The Grave Domain cleric allows you to cast [spare the dying](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/spare-the-dying) with a range of 30', instead of as a touch spell and as a bonus action if you want. The ability itself does not list any further requirements.

However there is a general requirement that you need a **clear path to the target** to target<sup>1</sup> a creature (in chapter 10, "Spellcasting" of the *PHB*, p.204).

> To target something, you must have a clear path to it, so it can’t be behind total cover.

A creature behind a corner would have total cover, so you cannot target it with the spell, and you cannot use *spare the dying* on it, wether you can see it, or not. (If the corner was of transparent crystal, it would still block an unobstructed path).

---

<sup>1</sup> In case you wonder, *spare the dying* does not use the word "target", but a spell that affects only a single creature such as this would consider that creature its target (*PHB* p. 204)

> A typical spell requires you to pick one or more targets
> to be affected by the spell’s magic. A spell's description
> tells you whether the spell targets creatures, objects, or
> a point of origin for an area of effect (described below).

See also here for [deeper discussion](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/152115/75095).

Comment: +1 I forgot of about the "clear path". Good point.

Comment: ^ I did, too. Pulled my answer because it was objectively wrong.